# VGA (D-Sub) for 1920x1200 Monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have 2 1920x1200 monitors of a single model that has DVI, DP and VGA ports. The Graphics card has a DVI, an HDMI and a VGA port. The specs of the card say:
Maximum Digital Resolution:2560x1600
Maximum VGA Resolution:2048x1536

So, as it seems, I can use the VGA port to use the other monitor to its maximum resolution(1900x1200). Am I right?
Moreover, are their any downside to not using a digital connectivity when it could have been achieved by plugging in a simple hdmi to dvi adapter in the hdmi port of the graphics?

N.B.- The monitor and the CPU are supposed to be at a distance of 3m, so the cable length will be a around 3m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the difference is not so much between the cables but more between the differences of digital and analog signals so you will get advantages using DVI such as sharper edges, less interference on the cable so again better quality images, it can cut out some 'flickering' on the screen compared to VGA.

This can be a very overly complicated subject and I've read a lot about it but in my honest opinion if you have top of the range equipment then go with DVI if your equipment is more budget then you must likely will not notice a great deal of difference.

It also makes a difference what your planning on using the PC for, if your doing graphics work or gaming then again DVI to give you a cleaner picture and may reduce eye strain.

The third thing to keep in mind is how good is your eye sight, some people comment that one monitor looks better than another monitor, both look the same to me in most cases :)

Comment: It also depends on how well the VGA input was implemented, I've run into a number of TVs with utterly awful VGA inputs, those on monitors seem much better not quite as good as digital but more than good enough for day to day use.